# Can we add something about outdoors to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

We've been getting numerous questions recently that would probably fit better at [The Great Outdoors SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com), but get asked at *Travel Answers* because *Travel Answers* is more visible and it's tangibly on-topic, because many people do outdoor sports specifically when travelling.  Some examples:

- *https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/15945/2509* (migration flag in progress)
- *https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14711/2509* (was migrated)
- *[Do I have to expect snow at 3900 meters above sea level during summer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14712/2509)* (was not migrated)

Currently, our FAQ describes what Travel SE is about:

> customs & border crossing, visas and other travel documents such as permits 
>   accommodation: camping, hostels & backpackers, guesthouses, B&B's, hotels, renting a villa on a trip 
>   loyalty programmes: frequent flyer points and hotel advantages 
>   health and safety issues related to travel 
>   modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport 
>   finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange 
>   working while on the go (WWOOFing, volunteer travel etc) - not immigration or work visas, see below

Camping would be one example that fits either on *Travel Answers* or on *The Great Outdoors*.  The FAQ does not provide any guidance as to where it would fit.  There's a [camping in national forests question on Travel Answers](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1283/2509), and a virtually identical [camping in the wild question on The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1819/566).  There's a snow is Yosemite question at [Travel Answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14712/2509) and a virtually identical one at [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3634/566).  We're clearly duplicating efforts here.

We've had discussion in the past on how to distinguish between the two; for example, see *[Travel vs. Outdoor SE, or, do we need the [outdoor-activities] tag?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/991/2509)* and *[Is being answered a reason not to migrate?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1283/2509)*.

**Can we add something about this to the FAQ?**  I'd like to see a policy that clearly defines whether questions belong to *Travel Answers* or to *The Great Outdoors*.  It would be good if we can then add some lines to the FAQ.  For example, at *camping* we could write (*See also The Great Outdoors*), and/or we could explicitly point to *The Great Outdoors* as an additional point *Things to do while travelling*.

After all, I might have a national forest close to my backyard and not need any travelling to get there.  It never occurred to me to even search *Travel Answers* for either camping in the wild or mountain snow (the latter not being travel related in any way).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see that you're going to get such a thing.  There are plenty of overlaps on stackexchange. Many questions are suitable for both sites.

Some questions on programmers are just as suitable on stackoverflow (although many aren't).

My process flow goes:

Is it on topic? Yes? It stays.  No? Does it fit on another site? If yes, then migrate, otherwise close.

Comment: I think the process flow should be slightly changed to include - has it been flagged for migration and has no answers? If so, migrate. Has a mod from outdoors requested it and it has no answers? If so migrate.

Comment: @RoryAlsop knew somebody would query it ;) The above flow was assuming no flags - just when I see a new question and evaluate it.  However even if another mod has requested it - if it's valid on our site, I see no reason to shift it across - the OP asked it on here, and it's on-topic, it should stay where they chose to ask it.

Comment: Sure - I was more trying to take account of the case where no answers appear.